# template class with lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++17

Let suppose you go and do something on each element of a vector or array. Let also suppose we want to count all elements that "satisfy" some predicate.

Because the lambda must have state, we can do something like this:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

template<typename T, class F>
class CountAcummulator{
    size_t count = 0;

    F f;

public:
    constexpr CountAcummulator(F f) : f(std::move(f)){}

    constexpr void operator()(T const &a){
        if (std::invoke(f, a))
            ++count;
    }

    constexpr size_t get() const{
        return count;
    }
};

int main(){
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto f = [](int a){
        return a > 3;
    };

    CountAcummulator<int, decltype(f)> ca{ f };

    for(auto i : x){
        // do something
        ca(i);
    }

    return ca.get();
}
```

Link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pjtcCG

Unfortunately i found this very difficult to use. If we add projection (another lambda), this class will be unusable.

Is there any way this class to be improved so it is usable?

Comment: [`std::count_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count).

Comment: sure, but suppose we doing for_each of the array and meanwhile doing some other processing.

Comment: Look at the example implementation and mimick it. You do not need a custom class to implement this algorithm.

Comment: suppose i have vector of objects, I need to do several count_if, min, max, sum (accumulate) and delete some uniq_ptr. and I need to do this in single pass.

Comment: What about it do you want improved?  If you just want general critique, this may be the wrong website.

Comment: If you are writing your own loop with lots of content, just write `if (f(i)) ++count;` in it too. It makes little sense to encapsulate just this small part.

Comment: Why don’t you just add the state update to the lambda (via a reference capture)?

Comment: @n.m. this is what i am doing, but i wanted to research if there is better, zero cost way. however i found is ugly :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard algorithm called [std::count_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) that counts all elements that satisfy a predicate. This should be the preferred method to use unless you have good reason not to.

```
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto f = [](int a){
        return a > 3;
    };

    return std::count_if(std::begin(x), std::end(x), f);
}
```

Comment: however, count_if can count one thing at a time. what if I want to find 10 different counts and do some expensive job at the same time. Also what if the iterators are expensive as well and going forward on the iterator is very slow?

Comment: @Nick I would probably use std::accumulate for counting multiple things at a time. I don't see what having slow iterators matters - you're going to have to iterate through them one time no matter what you do. No algorithm will avoid having to visit each element once.

Comment: if iterators are slow, 3x count will take 3x more time.

about accumulate, I can accumulate in std::touple?

Comment: You can use any type as the accumulator, including tuple.